# Assign JsonArray value to a variable matching case class

Tags: json, scala, case-class

I am passing and payload which is similar as the `case class reportdata`, inside a class. And i need a to get the value of `report_data` which is a Option[JSArray],

I need assign that JSArray to a varible if that optional array matches the `case class reportdata`

```
case class Fields(
                      reportid: Option[Long],
                      report_data: Option[JsArray],
                      header :Option[JsArray],
                      footer :Option[JsArray]
                    )

case class reportdata(
                     customText : Option[String],
                     textAlignment: Option[String],
                     textSize : Option[Int],
                     pageHeight: Long,
                     pageWidth: Long
                     )
```

The Json i pass from the DB is case class type Fields, and it has 3 JSON Arrays. so i want select the json Array which matches the case class of report data and I should assign it to a new variable.

```
"reports": [
        {
            "reportid":513,
            "report_data":[
                {
                    "formatType": "text",
                    "value": "This is a sample text to be printed in the report"
                },
                {
                    "formatType": "text size",
                    "value": 12
                },
                {
                    "formatType": "text alignment",
                    "value" : "RIGHT"
                },
                {
                    "formatType": "page height",
                    "value" : "12"
                },
                {
                    "formatType": "page width",
                    "value" : "8"
                }
            ],
            "header": [
                {
                    "formatType": "text",
                    "value": "Test"
                },
                {
                    "formatType": "font size",
                    "value": 12
                }
            ],
            "footer": [
                {
                    "formatType": "text",
                    "value": "Test"
                },
                {
                    "formatType": "font size",
                    "value": 12
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What have you tried / what library do you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Dijon](https://github.com/pathikrit/dijon) FTW!

Here is a test that demonstrates how easily the "right" value can be found in samples like yours:

```
    import com.github.pathikrit.dijon._

    val json = parse(
      """{
        |"data":[
        |  {
        |    "formatType": "text",
        |    "value": "bgyufcie huis huids hufhsduhfsl hd"
        |  },
        |  {
        |    "formatType": "text size",
        |    "value": 12
        |  },
        |  {
        |    "formatType": "text alignment",
        |    "value" : "right"
        |  }
        |]
        |}""".stripMargin)

assert(json.data.toSeq.collect { 
  case obj if obj.formatType == "text alignment" => obj.value 
}.head == "right")
```